# How to find focused React component? (like document.activeElement)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, react-dom

If you had 500 components, each with a `ref`, how would you find which component has the user's focus? All components with a `ref` are focusable elements like `<input />`, `<textarea />`, etc. For simplicity, all of the `refs` are accessible from a single top-level component.

This is very simple if your React components have `classNames` - but if you want to find the `ref` of a `document.activeElement`, if there some way to achieve that without having to resort to classNames?

To touch on why we don't have `classNames`, we're using `JSS` via `emotion`. To have to manually assign everything a `className` just for this purpose would be rather absurd. No obvious alternative has occurred to me.

Comment: Is this something you could achieve with an `onFocus` event instead of using refs? Could you create a codesandbox?

Comment: Agreed with Dennis, you could use a focus handler to access any data available on the event object and store it in your state.

Answer (score 28):

This may be a good use case for a custom hook that hooks into the native DOM methods to track focus events and then returns the active element. This will log the active element every time a new element receives focus:

```
const useActiveElement = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(document.activeElement);
  
  const handleFocusIn = (e) => {
    setActive(document.activeElement);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('focusin', handleFocusIn)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('focusin', handleFocusIn)
  };
  }, [])
  
  return active;
}

const App = () => {
  const focusedElement = useActiveElement();
  
  useEffect(() => {
     if (focusedElement) {
       focusedElement.value && console.log(focusedElement.value);
     }
    console.log(focusedElement);
  }, [focusedElement])
  
  return (
    <div>
        <input type="text"/>
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, correlating this element with your refs could prove tricky, as you'd need to keep a collection of the refs to search through which would probably involve giving each element its own [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to store in an Array or something similar. But depending on what you need to do with the element once it's focused, it may not be necessary. For example, the code I posted above will log the value of the input if it exists. It would help to know more specifically what your use case is for tracking this data.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like that, react gives you an option to track/focus using **ref**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.button = React.createRef();
    this.textarea = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
}

focusTextInput() {
    // this.textInput.current.focus();
    this.button.current.focus();
    // this.textarea.current.focus();
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" ref={this.textInput} />
        <button ref={this.button}>something</button>
        <textarea ref={this.textarea}></textarea>
        <input
              type="button"
              value="Focus the text input"
              onClick={this.focusTextInput}
        />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

You can get a detail [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)